# Cloud Functions alternative with Secret Manager without timeout quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

With so many GCP options, what is the best Cloud Functions alternative to store a `node.js` code on GCP that should be executed without any time restriction and with access to the [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager)?

For a better illustration, the existing `node.js` code is triggered using an HTTPS callable function that receives `JSON` data from external sources. The code has some work threads dispatching `setInterval` methods that don't work as expected due to the [time restriction imposed by Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/timeout).

At first, it seemed that [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) would be a suitable solution, until realizing Secret Manager doesn't support it (as per not listed on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/using-other-products), at least).

Comment: Can you check if [using secrets for Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets) will work out for you?

Comment: The doc only shows product that has direct integration with Secret Manager without needing to use the libraries in some cases; saying it's not listed it's like saying you cannot access Secret Manager from your local computer just because it is not listed. You can access from App Engine using the libs https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/secret-manager/latest

As well asking for recommendations is off-topic in SO

Comment: What should others say if it is really not listed and no references are made to App Engine there? It’s just curious your personal assumption that “saying it’s not listed is like saying bla bla bla”. Also note this doesn’t ask for recommendations, but alternatives available in GCP.

Comment: Because the title of the docs says: "Using Secret Manager with other products" and not "Products that only can be used with Secrets Manager". In addition if we read more in the docs we can find the following https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/accessing-the-api#app-engine

Comment: Now, regarding your main question: App Engine in fact has "time restrictions" but maybe fit for what you need. In the case of GAE Standard it has a timeout of 24 hours when used with basic and manual scaling. If the code needs more time, I think there's no serverless alternative and maybe a VM is the best option. Whatever you choose, you can access Secrets Manager using the libraries or the approaches you mention from the "Using Secret Manager with other products" doc if apply